# What is Dora Milaje's actual jurisdiction?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-falcon-and-the-winter-soldier

In the 4th episode of the first season of *The Falcon & The Winter Soldier*, the Dora Milaje cross paths with John Walker when they arrive to apprehend Zemo.

> **John**: The Dora Milaje don't have jurisdiction here...
> **Ayo**: The Dora Milaje have jurisdiction wherever the Dora Milaje find themselves to be.

[-Script-](https://tvshowtranscripts.ourboard.org/viewtopic.php?f=951&t=43398)

Does the Dora Milaje really not have a limit of jurisdiction, or is Ayo bluffing to make John uncomfortable here?

Comment: Inside Wakanda, obvs

Comment: I think they're just saying they don't really care about the laws of anyone, but Wakanda. What is jurisdiction to the Wakandans? They're basically untouchable to the outside world.

Comment: @Villan What makes you say that 'they are untouchable'?

Comment: Probably not "untouchable" so much as "unconcerned about any anticipated resistance to their actions".

Comment: An actual international legal framework that allows the Dora Milaje to operate as they see fit seems unlikely.

Comment: @Sandun Technologically their country is super advanced to the rest of the world. If they just go back to Wakanda, who will go get them out of that santuary? Then the U.S. will sanction Wakanda, but guess what? Wakanda is self reliant as far as I know. The Laws of the world just are irrelevant to them. They're living on their own planet basically, but will interfere when they are sleighted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think they're just saying they don't really care about the laws of anyone, but Wakanda. What is jurisdiction to the Wakandans? I don't think they feel threatened by anyone on earth.

This is pretty common in comics in general. The Justice League constantly battle with world laws, but feel pretty immune to the consequences. And even Storm from the X-men has fought with War-Machine for trying to operate a mission in U.S. jurisdiction. They're doing what they think is just, not what laws dictate is just.

So the answer to the actual question is, they only have "jurisdiction" in Wakanda. They just don't care.